# ASP.NET MVC FileNotFound Error upon Adding Strongly-Typed View

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ioerror

I am an ASP.NET MVC newbie.  I am getting a very strange error when I attempt to add a new strongly-type view in my controller.  I am using a basic class, with no dependencies, with the View content set to "List".  I am using a master page.  The view name is a standard "Index".  This used to work just fine but it all of a sudden started giving me this error every time:

[Error http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7707/mvcioerr.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7707/mvcioerr.png)
*(Thanks for resizing [my image](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7707/mvcioerr.png), Stack Overflow, instead of putting it in an overflowed container like a gentleman. And also, thanks for giving me no way to turn the image into a hyperlink to the [original image](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7707/mvcioerr.png))*

The name of the DLL changes on the error message every time.  I have tried restarting my machine, and that did not work.  I do not know what else to try.  Can anybody help me resolve this error?  It is preventing me from continuing this code binge (which I rarely get to go on), and it is really giving me a bad impression of ASP.NET MVC.

I [tweeted](http://twitter.com/JoshStodola/status/8394853795) to the men, but was ignored.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC Version 1.0 is what I am using, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reinstall ASP.NET MVC :
 Remove both **Microsoft ASP.NET MVC** and **Microsoft ASP.NET MVC - Visual Studio tools** from your Control Panel and reinstall ASP.NET MVC.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have the "Visual Studio tools" in there, but will try removing MVC and re-installing.  Thanks!

Comment: It worked.  Unfortunately, it wiped out all of my custom T4 templates with it.  I should have them backed up somewhere :)

Comment: Oops Sorry for that.
Forget to mention back up your projects before uninstall :(